# iPhone Simulator slow sometimes, fast sometimes

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

On my OpenGL ES 2.0 App -

Using the iPhone simulator sometimes is dirt slow on my development machines (MacBook Pro 2.4ghz 8GB RAM, MacBook Air 1.4ghz 2GB RAM, both with 320M), sometimes is very fast.

In fact if I compile and run the debugger and its slow, I simply click "STOP" on Xcode, and run again.  Sometimes it's fast, if not I "STOP", and run again.  There's a huge range of maybe 2FPS -> 20FPS and it seems completely random how fast or slow it runs.  Whatver speed it starts at, it remains consistent until I stop and restart the simulator.

I really started noticing this on my Air because everything is proportionally slower, but the problem exists on my MBP too.  Does anyone else experience this?  Any thoughts?

Using 3.2.5 w/4.2 iOS SDK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have noticed this.  I find if i quit and relaunch the simulator the performance comes back up.  Occasionally I can get the speed back by deleting the app from the simulator and then compiling again.  I hope these tips help.

Comment: At least I'm not alone. What hardware/software for the machine? And, welcome to SO :)

Comment: MBP 2.16 with the most recent set.  I have just ignored the issue mostly and thanks for the welcome!

Comment: Happens to me too...like once every other launch. Very annoying. I wish there was a way to fix it.